# How to upgrade from Xubuntu 21.10 to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu

can I seamlessly upgrade from Xubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04? Thank you for reading. Greetings

Comment: 22.04 hasn't been released yet, so I would wait. You should be prompted to upgrade once it's available. Or you can run `sudo do-release-upgrade` at that time. If you have problems, please search and research before asking. If you still need help, make sure you provide clear details about the problem. Share what you found in your research and tell us why it didn't work for you. https://askubuntu.com/tour | https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See also: [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477)

Comment: From 20.10 to 22.04 as per your title - No.  From 21.10 to 22.04 **after** release - Yes.   Please ensure you facts are correct & don't contradict.  *Also note: the *seamless* upgrade assumes no 3rd party packages; if you have added 3rd party it'll depend on what you've added. Some will prevent upgrade from occurring, others will create problems; some are no problem.  It'll be great if not using 3rd party packages though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Thank you so very much Guiverc and Nmath.
 
The main point of my question was upgrade from Xubuntu to Ubuntu. 

I recently put together a desktop and installed from scratch Ubuntu 21.04, or what I thought it to be, because when I logged in there are ubuntu options at the upper right corner but never understood what they are for as I always end up with the same Xubuntu.

That's why I was asking.

I use Ubuntu almost from start. I remember there were free Ubuntu install disks floating around at work.
Yes I am also using 3rd party Nvidia drivers.
Many thanks for your help. Best regards

Comment: I'm involved with QA; and keep a system with each release on it; when one reaches EOL it becomes a test system for another release; usually via re-install; eg. when 21.04 reached EOL it became a 22.04 system, but it's often backwards (ie. to 20.04 as I wanted to QA-test 20.04.4 for example).  The re-install I use doesn't touch user files, re-installs the additional packages I *manually installed* (from Ubuntu repos) so I have my music, my non-default music player all ready on re-install; and I can move forward/backward -- but there are complexities (esp. when going backwards) with this

Comment: Your question is missing specifics (ie. *commands used, often to fix issues, can impact the results, & I have the benefit of know much of what I'm doing so don't copy/paste commands if I don't understand the effects*) which include packages... Also how changes are made (*global changes do not survive the install type I mentioned generally; but user config changes do*) and results can vary on packages installed (esp. if going to an older release/backwards), but you gave little specifics. You mention an issue with specifics that are unclear; we cannot answer questions that aren't clear.

Comment: Dear Guiverc,

Thank you. What I will do is to upgrade as usual and if I have issues that I cannot solve, I will get back to here. So we can close the thread. Best regards, Zuheyr